# I want to modify a jquery plugin for bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am in need of using a mini calendar for picking up dates. I cannot find a suitable plugin for twitter bootstrap but what i have found is a plugin for selecting dates (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) which involves firing up a calender when the calender button is clicked. I want to know whether is there any way possible that we do not need to click a button; rather the calendar is displayed permanently and we can then select a date and use its info. There must be!

Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: You could write the code to display it permanently!

Comment: Why not just use the jQuery UI datepicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use `.datepicker('show')` to display datepicker without clicks. Also there are events(`'hide'`) you can track to prevent its hiding. All needed info you can find on the page you provided(http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/). Hope it helps!